# How to set the type of CustomEvent detail property in typescript

Tags: typescript

I use a lot of custom events and one blind spot in the typescript static checking is the type of detail in `CustomEvent`. A lot of refactorings suffer because of this blind spot. To compensate I have created a global type for `CustomEvent`. Since I am using it all over the app I do not want to have imports all over the place just for this type.

**globals.d.ts** - generic custom event

```
interface VsCustomEvent<T> extends CustomEvent { detail: T }
```

I would have expected this to work

```
handleSomeEvent = ({detail}: CustomEvent<boolean> ) => {
    this.doSomething(detail)
}
```

Is there a better solution than the global generic?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are able to define a base generic globally and then derive actual types from it if needed:

```
// globals.d.ts
interface CustomEvent<Detail> {
  detail: Detail;
}
```

```
// some-file.ts
interface BooleanEvent extends CustomEvent<boolean> {}
interface StringEvent extends CustomEvent<string> {}

function handleBoolean({ detail }: BooleanEvent): void {
  // `detail` is a boolean
}

function handleString({ detail }: StringEvent): void {
  // `detail` is a string
}
```